# Different Regression Lines?

Tags: statistics, regression

Hi quick question with regression. If the coefficients of a simple regression line, B0 and B1, are the same then why are the regression lines of y on x and x on y different given the condition r^2 < 1. I have tried all the manipulation and graphical analysis I can but can't seem to see why this is happening. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You received good explanations from user 44197 but let me add a few points.

When you perform a regression (linear or nonlinear) for $Y = F(a_0,a_1,a_2,...,X]$, the assumption is that there is no error on the $X$'s and that the errors on the $Y$'s are normally distributed. So, you minimize the sum of the squared errors on the $Y$'s. I suppose that you understand that the reverse process will lead to another regression.

The problem is more complex when there are errors on both $X$'s and $Y$'s. In this case, orthogonal distance regression is typically used
 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares will give you good explanations. In this case, the regression is unique.

Comment: To note: orthogonal distance and total least squares is not scale invariant and so is difficult to justify if $x$ and $y$ are measured in different units or have substantially different dispersions.

Comment: @Henry. I totally agree with you. I took this case to show that there are some regression lines which are unique and do not suffer the classical problem encountered by the OP when switching from $Y(X)$ to $X(Y)$.

Answer (score 0):

In one you are trying to write a formula for $y$ in terms of $x$. The error in the fit is the **vertical** distance from the data to the regression line.

In the second case the error is the **horizontal** distance from the data to the regression line.

Minimizing the sum of **vertical** errors is not the same as minimizing the sum of **horizontal** errors. In fact the discrepancy depends on $r^2-1$.

Answer (score 0):

To save effort, let's assume the means of the original data $x$s and $y$s are both $0$, that their standard deviations are $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$ are positive, and that the covariance $\sigma_{xy}$ is positive; the correlation coefficient $r = \dfrac{\sigma_{xy}}{\sigma_x\sigma_y}$ will therefore also be positive though not more than $1$.

Then one possible line for the graph between the points is $\dfrac{y}{\sigma_y}= \dfrac{x}{\sigma_x}$, i.e. $y =  \dfrac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x} x$.  You could easily end up with something close to this drawing by hand.  If the correlation coefficient was $r=1$ then all the points would lie on this line.

But regressing $y$ on $x$ will not give you this result for $r\lt 1$, as it is trying to minimise the sum of squares of the vertical residuals, and it will do this by giving $y = \dfrac{\sigma_{xy}}{\sigma_x^2} x$, i.e. $y =  r \dfrac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x}x$, reducing the slope.

Meanwhile regressing $x$ on $y$ will give you a different result for $r\lt 1$, as it is trying to minimise the sum of squares of the horizontal residuals, and it will do this by giving  $x = \dfrac{\sigma_{xy}}{\sigma_y^2} y$, i.e.   $y =  \dfrac1r \dfrac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x}x$ and increasing the slope.

One lesson to draw from this is that a lower correlation will increase the difference between regressing $y$ on $x$ and regressing $x$ on $y$.